# JIT deoptimization, reason="constraint". Why JIT deoptimizes method?

Tags: java, jvm, jit

could someone point me in direction which might lead me to get why JIT deoptimizes my loop? (OSR). It looks like it gets compiled once by C1 and then its deoptimized multiple times (I can see tens or maybe hundred logs which starts with <deoptimized...>)

This is the class which contains that important loop:

```java
@SynchronizationRequired
public class Worker implements Runnable
{
    private static final byte NOT_RUNNING = 0, RUNNING = 1, SHUTDOWN = 2, FORCE_SHUTDOWN = 3;
    private static final AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater<Worker> isRunningFieldUpdater =
            AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater.newUpdater(Worker.class, "isRunning");

    private volatile int isRunning = NOT_RUNNING;

    private final Queue<FunkovConnection> tasks = new SpscUnboundedArrayQueue<>(512);

    /**
     * Executing tasks from queue until closed.
     */
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (isRunning())
        {
            return;
        }

        while (notClosed())
        {
            FunkovConnection connection = tasks.poll();
            if (null != connection)
            {
                connection.run();
            }
        }

        if (forceShutdown())
        {
            setNonRunning();
            return;
        }

        FunkovConnection connection;
        while ((connection = tasks.poll()) != null)
        {
            connection.run();
        }

        setNonRunning();
    }

    public void submit(FunkovConnection connection)
    {
        tasks.add(connection);
    }


    /**
     * Shutdowns worker after it finish processing all pending tasks on its queue
     */
    public void shutdown()
    {
        isRunningFieldUpdater.compareAndSet(this, RUNNING, SHUTDOWN);
    }

    /**
     * Shutdowns worker after it finish currently processing task. Pending tasks on queue are not handled
     */
    public void shutdownForce()
    {
        isRunningFieldUpdater.compareAndSet(this, RUNNING, FORCE_SHUTDOWN);
    }

    private void setNonRunning()
    {
        isRunningFieldUpdater.set(this, NOT_RUNNING);
    }

    private boolean forceShutdown()
    {
        return isRunningFieldUpdater.get(this) == FORCE_SHUTDOWN;
    }

    private boolean isRunning()
    {
        return isRunningFieldUpdater.getAndSet(this, RUNNING) == RUNNING;
    }

    public boolean notClosed()
    {
        return isRunningFieldUpdater.get(this) == RUNNING;
    }
}
```

JIT logs:

```
 1. <task_queued compile_id='535' compile_kind='osr' method='Worker run ()V' bytes='81' count='1' backedge_count='60416' iicount='1' osr_bci='8' level='3' stamp='0,145' comment='tiered' hot_count='60416'/>
 2. <nmethod compile_id='535' compile_kind='osr' compiler='c1' level='3' entry='0x00007fabf5514ee0' size='5592' address='0x00007fabf5514c10' relocation_offset='344' insts_offset='720' stub_offset='4432' scopes_data_offset='4704' scopes_pcs_offset='5040' dependencies_offset='5552' nul_chk_table_offset='5560' oops_offset='4624' metadata_offset='4640' method='Worker run ()V' bytes='81' count='1' backedge_count='65742' iicount='1' stamp='0,146'/>
 3. <deoptimized thread='132773' reason='constraint' pc='0x00007fabf5515c24' compile_id='535' compile_kind='osr' compiler='c1' level='3'>
<jvms bci='37' method='Worker run ()V' bytes='81' count='1' backedge_count='68801' iicount='1'/>
</deoptimized>
4. <deoptimized thread='132773' reason='constraint' pc='0x00007fabf5515c24' compile_id='535' compile_kind='osr' compiler='c1' level='3'>
<jvms bci='37' method='Worker run ()V' bytes='81' count='1' backedge_count='76993' iicount='1'/>
</deoptimized>
5.<deoptimized thread='132773' reason='constraint' pc='0x00007fabf5515c24' compile_id='535' compile_kind='osr' compiler='c1' level='3'>
<jvms bci='37' method='Worker run ()V' bytes='81' count='1' backedge_count='85185' iicount='1'/>
</deoptimized>
6. <deoptimized thread='132773' reason='constraint' pc='0x00007fabf5515c24' compile_id='535' compile_kind='osr' compiler='c1' level='3'>
<jvms bci='37' method='Worker run ()V' bytes='81' count='1' backedge_count='93377' iicount='1'/>
</deoptimized>
```

Two questions here:

1. What could be the reason for deoptimization? "constraint" seems not that meaningful to me
2. Why there is so many logs about deoptimization, not just one? It look likes it's compiled once but decompiled multipile times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm glad that @aran's suggestion helped in your case, however, it's just a lucky coincidence. After all, JIT inlining options affect many things, including the compilation order, timings, and so on. In fact, deoptimization has nothing to do with inlining.

I was able to reproduce your problem, and here is my analysis.

We see in [HotSpot sources](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ffbcf1b0a7d9484e95a82f667fcbabd290449711/src/hotspot/share/runtime/deoptimization.cpp#L1691) that `<deoptimized>` message is printed by `Deoptimization::deoptimize_single_frame` function. Let's engage [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) to find where this function is called from. To do so, add the following JVM option:

```
-agentlib:asyncProfiler=start,event=Deoptimization::deoptimize_single_frame,file=deopt.html
```

Here is the relevant part of the output:

[image: deoptimize_single_frame]

So, the deoptimization reason is `Runtime1::counter_overflow` function. A method compiled by C1 at tier 3, counts invocations and backward branches (loop iterations). Every 2<sup>Tier3BackedgeNotifyFreqLog</sup> iterations a method calls `Runtime1::counter_overflow` to decide whether it should be recompiled at a higher tier.

In your logs we see that `backedge_count` increments exactly by 8192 (2<sup>13</sup>), and the bytecode at index 37 is `goto` corresponding to `while (notClosed())` loop.

```
<jvms bci='37' method='Worker run ()V' bytes='81' count='1' backedge_count='76993' iicount='1'/>
<jvms bci='37' method='Worker run ()V' bytes='81' count='1' backedge_count='85185' iicount='1'/>
<jvms bci='37' method='Worker run ()V' bytes='81' count='1' backedge_count='93377' iicount='1'/>
```

When the counter overflows (every 8192 iterations), the JVM checks if an OSR compiled method for the given bytecode index is ready (it might not be ready yet, since JIT compilation runs in background). But if the JVM finds such method, it performs OSR transition by deoptimizing the current frame and replacing it with the corresponding OSR method.

It turns out that in your example the JVM finds an existing OSR method compiled at tier 3. Basically, it deoptimizes `Worker.run` frame compiled at tier 3, and replaces it by exactly the same method! This repeats again and again, until C2 finishes its background job. Then `Worker.run` is replaced by tier 4 compilation, and everything becomes fine.

Of course, this should not normally happen. This is actually a JVM bug [JDK-8253118](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8253118). It has been fixed in JDK 16 and will be likely backported to JDK 11u. I have verified that excessive deoptimization does not happen with JDK 16 Early-Access builds.

Answer (score 2):

### SPOILER

**This was a lucky shot, as @apangin comments. If you want to know what really happens, do not waste time reading this answer.**

[image: ![me while answering this question]  --  *pic of me while answering*

---

Although the JIT compiler may inline aggressively in some cases, it still has its own time constraints, and won't inline if that's going to take significant time to do. As a result, a **method is eligible for inlining only if its bytecode size is less than 35 bytes** (*by default*).

In your case, your methods are **81 bytes** of size, hence not eligible:

**`<jvms bci='37' method='Worker run ()V' bytes='81' ...`**

> **[Java Performance: The Definitive Guide by Scott Oaks](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-performance-the/9781449363512/ch04.html)**
>
> *The basic decision about whether to inline a method depends on how hot
> it is and its size. The JVM determines if a method is hot (i.e.,
> called frequently) based on an internal calculation; it is not
> directly subject to any tunable parameters. If a method is eligible
> for inlining because it is called frequently, then it will be inlined
> only if its bytecode size is less than 325 bytes (or whatever is
> specified as the -XX:MaxFreqInlineSize=N flag). **Otherwise, it is
> eligible for inlining only if it is small: less than 35 bytes** (or
> whatever is specified as the -XX:MaxInlineSize=N flag).*

**In order to make your methods be inlined**, you could change the inline size limit by command line, specifying **`-XX:MaxInlineSize=N`**.

As a test, you could try specifying something like
`-XX:MaxInlineSize=90` in order to check if those methods are now inlined.

***To the reader - the suggestion above "fixed" the issue(*not really fixed*). How? No idea. I was even given the correct answer tick lol***

---

### Appendix

(*I'll just let this here as seems cool*)

--
**[`Workload characterization of JVM languages`](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/spe.2337)**

*`Aibek S. Lukas S. Lubomír B. Andreas S. Andrej P. Yudi Z. Walter B.`*

[image]

Comment: You were right, thanks! It works correctly if I set `-XX:MaxInlineSize=90`. So I have to make my method little smaller. 

About threads - there is the same thread='132773' (number) so I guess its related to the same thread

Comment: But the flipside is that the JIT has apparently NOT determined that these method calls are hot.  So the performance benefit of inlining them is likely to be less than you would expect (or hope).  I wonder if it would better if you just let the JIT do its thing.  Have you done some application level benchmarking and profiling?   Does that tell you that these methods are actually a performance hotspot?

Comment: @StephenC yes, thinking about the same. Also the docs suggest being careful here when changing the default inline max size. It's like *hey, if we are doing this, is for a reason*: the cost of inlining those methods may not compensate the possible optimization that is obtained. I will update the answer to point this out, thanks for the comment Stephen

Comment: @Stephen C  if I get some spare time I promise benchmarking this on different hosts and Java versions. Inlining methods from 30 to 100 bytes. I think It Will be interesting. If anyone interesed, will be updating this answer while getting some results. I was thinking on a multithreaded system with both Hot, small and Big methods.Not only including times but also CPU and memoriy profilling. If anyone has a suggestion please comment!

Comment: @aran - my suggestions about benchmarking, etc were really intended for minizibi.  As a rule, one should benchmark / profile before diving into specific ways to optimize or tune application code.

Comment: @Stephen C yeah, but this intrigued me. Muy goal is yo obtain a template/generic Code intended for benchmarking. Once obtained, the interesting thing would be the different behaviour on different versions and hardware specs. This would be done on the cloud si specific detalls of the offered cloud servers should be checked(for Example, an aws machine with 2 CPUs and other one with 4cpus not only differ on the core quantiy, as each one could mount a different Intel CPU family). im somehow done to this so I could get something I Believe.

Comment: The answer is confusing - seems like misunderstanding about what deoptimization is. "Deoptimization" is not the same as "Suboptimal compilation". And it has nothing to do with inlining.

Comment: @apangin I never intended to compare deoptimization with suboptimal compilation; If so, I would appreciate where in the answer I do it, so I can fix it. *Inlining is the most beneficial optimization the compiler can make, particularly for object-oriented* -- This quote is from Scott Oaks' guide book; How is that inlining has nothing to do with optimization? I'm asking with all respect here.

Comment: @apangin again, sincerely, I'm asking with all respect, since your knowledge is much more than mine. So I may be wrong with some of the statements here. My sincere intention is to know where I'm mistaken. Thanks again

Comment: Deoptimization means that the compiler needs to “undo” a previous compilation. In this case, as a Tiered compilation (shown in the logs), the methods (after being "optimized" by the C2 compiler) are "compiled to a previous state" by the JVM. Anyway, most of the cases in which this scenario happens, the "deoptimization" is making the code faster indeed

Comment: @aran Indeed, inlining is the most important optimization. But the question is about **de**optimization, which is a different concept. There is no such reason of deoptimization as *"because JIT is not inlining your methods"*. I don't know why you've made such conclusion, but your first sentence does not seem right, and thus the rest of the answer (which is solely about inlining) is irrelevant. But I don't mind, since it somehow helped the OP anyway :)

Comment: @apangin after some further reads, I am starting to get your point. I need to read some more to fully understand thou. My link was optimization-inlining / but I may mislead deoptimization/not inlining.

Comment: @apangin sorry for all this spamming, but are my last statements on the comment side correct? Or am I missing something also there?

Comment: @aran What statements? [Here](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/HotSpotGlossary.html) is the definition of deoptimization. The common reasons for deoptimization are 1) invalidating speculatively compiled code when a speculative precondition fails; 2) replacing C1-compiled code with a better optimized C2 code; 3) switching to interpreter for debugging.

Comment: @apangin sorry, I meant the comment that starts with "Deoptimization means that the...." -- Thanks for that link as well. Sincerely, i like being corrected by people like you, as it means I'll learn something new today

Comment: Yes, in this case deoptimization is needed to switch from less optimized code to more optimized code. It is done through a short intermediate step: C1->interpreter->C2. As OP correctly noticed, such deoptimization should happen just once for a single method. In practice it happened multiple times due to the mentioned JVM bug.

Comment: I won't bother you more, enough commenting, sorry! Seems like this concepts are far more complicated than I initially tought. Will read about this, for sure. Thank you for your time, asked OP to mark yours as correct. Sincere thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue recently on an aarch64 platform. Some interesting findings:

1. The excessive deopts does not happen all the time on aarch64 but it never happens on the x86 machine that I tested;
2. This issue causes a huge run-to-run variance (>30% in my case) between excessive deopts happen and not happen;
3. After applying the patch mentioned by @apagin, the excessive deopts issue is gone and the performance becomes stable. However, it is lower than the highest performance before the patch applied. Have you checked if the patch causes a performance loss before? @apagin.

Comment: It seems the massive deopts still exist even the patch is applied according to a few more tests